# Android SQLite query where column is not null and not empty

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I cannot figure out the syntax for the .query call. I need to select all records that match a certain column that do not have a null or empty value for a second (different) column

my best attempt:

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DatabaseOpenHelper.TABLE_ROOMS, mAllColumns,
    DatabaseOpenHelper.KEY_ROOM_HOSPITAL_ID
    + " =? AND " + DatabaseOpenHelper.KEY_ISO + " IS NOT NULL OR NOT ?",
    new String[]{String.valueOf(hospitalId), ""}, null, null, null);
```

This is returning ALL records. If I use AND in place of OR, it returns records matching hospitalId, but ignores the NOT NULL OR NOT "" part.

Any tips? Should I use a rawQuery call?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I believe the correct syntax would be:

```
AND key IS NOT NULL AND key != ""
```

where `key` is your *column*

Answer (score 6):

If multiple spaces can be in your column and you also want to treat them as empty values use `TRIM`

```sql
column_name IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(column_name," ") != ""
```

Comment: Or even TRIM(column_name) since space is used as the trim character by default.