# Choose only NOT NULL strings in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to choose only NON NULL String from `String[] groupFrom = new String[]{Database.DATABASE_GROUP_1};`

to pass to the adpater:

```
  SimpleCursorTreeAdapter simplecursortreeAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(
                this,
                cursor,
                R.layout.list_group,
                groupFrom,
                groupTo,
                R.layout.list_child,
                childFrom,
                childTo
        );
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372918/android-sqlite-query-where-column-is-not-null-and-not-empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SQLite query where column is not null and not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372918/android-sqlite-query-where-column-is-not-null-and-not-empty)

Comment: It is not .i've tried what was suggested but it doesnt work for me, i have different design , i have edited the text so you can see my design structure . do you think i can apply what was suggested in the link for me? and how with code please

Comment: i m new to android so i have based on this to create what i want which is expendable listview with prepopulated Sqlite database : https://github.com/JorgeAmVF/android-prepopulated-sqlite-database/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jorgeamvf/prepopulatedsqlitedatabase/MainActivity.java         My design structure is exactly like this

Answer (score 0):

Loop through with something similar to:

```
if (groupform[i] != null)
// Do stuff
```

I'm adapting this from here:

[How can I check whether an array is null / empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369967/how-can-i-check-whether-an-array-is-null-empty)

Comment: This is pretty inefficient when those rows can be excluded as part of the initial query

Comment: Could you give me a code to execute , i m new to android. i dont have experience in this